# Abandon multiline Python statement

Tags: python

I'm sure this question must have been asked before, but I can't for the life of me find it anywhere.

At the Python console, if I type a line expecting an indented block, the prompt changes accordingly, as in this example:

```
>>> for i in range(50):
...
```

How can I abandon this command in an elegant manner?

It's important because sometimes I have many open brackets, and abandoning the command becomes a game of working out how many brackets of various types I have to close before a Python exception will be thrown which I hit return:

```
>>> my_obj((((([[[(((
... # How do I get back to the normal prompt from here?
```

Comment: What's wrong with ^C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to abort the statement:

```
>>> for foo in bar:
... ^C
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Quoting from the [*"The Interpreter and Its Environment"* section of the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#error-handling):

> Typing the interrupt character (usually Control-C or DEL) to the primary or secondary prompt cancels the input and returns to the primary prompt.

Comment: Ah, yes, this works in Python launched from e.g. the linux terminal, but not in Spyder, my development environment. I didn't realise this was instrumental. Let me update my question.

Comment: @LondonRob: I'd say that *that* would be a bug. See https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1101 for a Mac equivalent in Spyder.

Comment: What should we do with this question @MartijnPieters? Should I edit the question to include the particular Spyder circumstances, make a new question, or just leave everything as it is?

Comment: I'd check with the Spyder developers to see why your session doesn't see `CTRL-C` interrupts. That'd be a bug, I think. It's unfortunate that you left out the Spyder angle, because that's a completely separate issue and altering your question would invalidate my answer entirely. I could then edit it to say: *I'd say bug in Spyder*, but that won't help you or future visitors very much.

Comment: As it stands, your question is fine, has an answer that future visitors might find helpful, and won't involve a possible spelunking expedition as to why Spyder might not handle the interrupt. I certainly won't know the answer to that one. :-)

Comment: Ok, I've discovered that Ctrl+C in Spyder works, but only *after* Enter is pressed following Ctrl+C. I'll raise a bug with the Spyder team.